# How to get an nvidia control panel?

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I have an Nvidia geforce 9500 gs card on Ubuntu 13.04. I downloaded the driver already but cannot change performance settings and my streaming video is very choppy. I can't even find System/administration/hardware drivers; it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 18):

To open the settings menu to allow installing additional proprietary drivers go to the *"System Settings..."* menu on the top panel. Choose *"Software and Updates"*

[image]

In the following window select then *"Additional Drivers"* tab:

[image]

This will let you select available stable proprietary drivers for your graphics card (above shown for a virtual machine).

[image]

On selecting the recommended *"Nvidia Current"* driver it will install on your system. Nvidia settings can then be accessed most easily from the Dash:

[image]

Answer (score 14):

You run the following command as **root**:

```
nvidia-settings
```

Depending on your version of Ubuntu, run

```
gksu nvidia-settings
```

[image: nvidia setings]