# Viewing NVIDIA Geforce card control panel from Ubuntu dual-boot with Windows 7

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-7, wubi

I have dual-booted Ubuntu using Wubi from win7 in a separate `G:` drive. Now where can I find my NVIDIA control panel that is installed in Windows 7?

Or do I have to install it again in Ubuntu? If yes, how do I do that?

I am using NVIDIA Geforce 9600GT

As I have installed Ubuntu from Wubi, does it means that I am using Windows 7 with an Ubuntu interface, so if Windows crashes the Ubuntu install will not work either? please help with the logic to clear my views with Wubi and a normal Ubuntu install via USB/DVD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wubi is commonly used to refer to the Windows UBuntu Installer, and also the Ubuntu that has been installed. But the Ubuntu install doesn't run in Windows like a VM. It's not hosted at all. The only virtual part is the Ubuntu partition.

So you can't use any programs, like the nvidia control panel, that are only installed in Windows. This is a completely separate OS.

Instead you'll need to refer to this: [how to get an nvidia control panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302518/how-to-get-an-nvidia-control-panel)

With regard to your additional questions about the difference between Wubi and a normal dual boot see here: [What's the difference between Wubi and a regular "alongside Windows" installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation)

Depending on how Windows is damaged, Wubi could still boot. But normally it's the Wubi install that gets damaged due to the increased potential for corruption due to the virtual disk.