# Xubuntu 14.04 driver for Nvidia 320M?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, versions

I checked my graphic card in the terminal by lspci | grep VGA and i've got this:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT216M [GeForce GT 320M] (rev a2)
```

So it is thinking that my graphic card is GT216M, can you give me a driver which will make it think that my card is GT 320M?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your graphics card is a GeForce GT 320M and your system recognizes it as such.
`GT216M` is the Chipset of your graphics card. So everything is fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks can you tell me a program like Nvidia Control Panel or something like this to manage the GPU settings?

Comment: Refer to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/302518/how-to-get-an-nvidia-control-panel) to get the control panel.

Comment: I have no options like turn-off v-sync, antialiasing and etc there

Comment: If you have the control panel the options should be there to. Google where they are or open another question.