# X server doesn't detect my second graphic card. ubuntu crashes when I try adding it manually to xorg.conf

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, xserver

I have 2 graphic cards (gtx 1070) attached to the mainboard. lspci detects both cards

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1b81 (rev a1)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1b81 (rev a1)
```

But there's only one "Device" Section in the xorg.conf file, and there's no graphic output on the card that X Server doesn't detect. I then tried adding the second graphic card manually, by adding `Screen      1  “FakeScreen1”` to `Section "ServerLayout"` and

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     “FakeMonitor1”
    VendorName     “Dummy”
    ModelName      “Dummy”
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1”
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Option         "Coolbits" "31"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     “FakeScreen1”
    Device         "Device1”
    Monitor        “FakeMonitor1”
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Coolbits" "31"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

to the end of the [xorg.conf](https://pastebin.com/nwPchdW2) file.
Ubuntu fails to boot after that, with this error on blank screen:
[image: error]

I then overwrite the tweaked xorg.conf with the [default-back-up-xorg.conf](https://pastebin.com/L2mMAwFX) and ubuntu reverts back to previous state with 2nd gpu not detected by X.

Where did I get it wrong? What can I do to make X recognized the second gpu?

Comment: Run the graphical tool - https://askubuntu.com/questions/302518/how-to-get-an-nvidia-control-panel

Comment: @bodhi.zazen both nvidia-smi and NVIDIA X Server settings detects both cards, but the xorg.conf created by nvidia-xconfig shows only one card :|. There's no graphic output on the second card that Xserver doesn't detect :( I forgot to add that to the question, adding now

Comment: On the graphical tool, run as root. Then get it setup the way you want, and save the settings to xorg.conf. Do not merge with previous. If that does not work I would have to google for an xorg.conf

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it. The problem was that I edited the xorg.conf file with Apple's Seirra TextEdit which converted all my `"` to `“` and `”` which aren't pure ascii characters. Therefore, X couldn't read the config file.