# Ubuntu goes slower than windows

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, firefox, video

*Hello and thanks for reading, i'm new on this community and i hope you can help me*

Long story short, i really like ubuntu, and installed multiple times, but always with the same problem, that in Ubuntu, when i open programs (firefox, even rithmbox) ubuntu freezes like 3 seconds or more and then starts the program, even when using the terminal. And worst, when i try to watch some youtube videos while searching another thing, sometimes ubuntu freezes completely, even if i'm only using firefox, long story short, my problem is that anything i do on ubuntu make's ubuntu freeze for a short time or completely, i really like ubuntu and want to use it, but i can't use my pc normally just to watch a video because it freezes.

My case in windows is different, i don't like windows as much as ubuntu, but on windows i can **not joking** install one program, while hearing a video (on youtube for example) and searching something on google, i can do everything i want to do on ubuntu (just use my pc normally) on windows and it rarely crashes (i think never happend)

So, sorry if i seem a little mad and just saying ubuntu is just problems, but is not that. I really want to use ubuntu, that's why even thought i tried everything i can't make ubuntu run swiftly, if i can do it i can finally delete windows.

My pc is:

Lenovo sl400 **you can watch all if you search that model on google**

```
Intel Core 2 Duo CPU T6570 2.10GHz x 2
1,9 gb  (2 gb)
Graphics unknown (i don't know if this is the problem, but i don't know how to search graphics drivers on ubuntu)
The lenovo sl400 graphics is : Geforce 9300M GS from NVIDIA. with 256MB GDDR3 of video memory
Gnome: 3.26.2
OS type 64 bits
Disk: 356,3 GB (I'm using more memory on ubuntu than in windows and the last goes faster)
```

I'm dualbooting with windows 10 (Windows 10 should be slower since it have a lot of stuff.. antivirus... etc... etc, but it doesn't).

OK, Finishing, i don't know if i have to move to another version of ubuntu, i don't know, an older version maybe? but well, i'll ask you since you know more than me about ubuntu.

Right know i have Ubuntu 17.10, the latest with has gnome.

*Many thanks for reading all of my blog, and sorry if you don't understand me at some point (English is not my first language), and more thanks if you can help me in this*

Comment: Probably this behaviour is due to the graphic driver.  Try to switch to NVidia driver. Read these answers how to do that: [How to get an nvidia control panel?](https://askubuntu.com/q/302518/566421) and [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/q/61396/566421)

Comment: IMHO, it has nothing to do with graphics. RAM usage may be interesting, also, Gnome 3 64bit may be too much for an old PC. Switching to Xubuntu or Mate is very much recommended.

Comment: What @mikewhatever said, there is also [this notorious memory bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1672297) in GNOME shell. Try using a lighter alternative, e.g. [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.net/), [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/), [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/).

Comment: Well, it's true, Ubuntu says i don't have any adittional drivers, so it's not graphics, maybe Pomsky is right, i should move, i like Ubuntu mate, but i really don't wanna switch so... maybe a older ubuntu version? or do i have to move to Xubuntu or Ubuntu Mate to use my Pc correctly?